# Failed TCP Socket connection to remotehost(EINVAL)

Tags: java, android

I am new and I've a question.
In android, I can't connect any remote address via TCP Socket. When I tried to connect, debugger shows an error:

```
Exception: failed to connect to /23.20.47.114 (port 9339) after 2000ms: connect failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument), OSVersion: 4.1.1(Jellybean)
```

And the code:

```
    void run(){
    Socket s=new Socket();
    s.bind(getAddress("192.168.0.45",8080));    <-It's bound successfully.
    s.connect(getAddress("23.20.47.114",9339));   <-Error
    writeData(s);
    }
    InetSocketAddress getAddress(String host, int port){[code]}
    void writeData(Socket so){[code]}
```

Note: This server is always open and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already bound the socket to a local IP address using `bind()`, so it does not make sense to also connect the same socket to a remote server. Try getting rid of the `bind()` statement.